# Key "player" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, key-value-observing, avplayeritem

I am observing AVPlayer object KVO notification in my class PCSPlayerNotification and I found the below crash.I am unable to reproduce this issue and I get this issue rarely.
I read this http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/204196-cannot-remove-observer-error.html and I found the cause of the issue must be with KVO notification that is sent by AVPlayer.But not sure how to fix ,can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Issue :

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Cannot update for observer <PCSPlayerNotification 0x7f78b70> for the key path "player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp" from <PCSPlayerNotification 0x7f78b70>, most likely because the value for the key "player" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the PCSPlayerNotification class.
```

Crash :

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2b2315a7 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39156c77 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2b2314ed -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Foundation                     0x2bed464d -[NSKeyValueNestedProperty object:withObservance:didChangeValueForKeyOrKeys:recurse:forwardingValues:]
4  Foundation                     0x2beb4151 NSKeyValueDidChange
5  Foundation                     0x2bea0991 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:]
6  VZFiOSMobile                   0x4f33f1 (Missing)
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x396c1c83 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x396c1c6f _dispatch_client_callout
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x396cd553 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2b1f7891 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2b1f5fb1 __CFRunLoopRun
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2b142b51 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2b142963 CFRunLoopRunInMode
14 GraphicsServices               0x326501a9 GSEventRunModal
15 UIKit                          0x2e794c91 UIApplicationMain
16 VZFiOSMobile                   0x272c1d main (main.m:16)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x396ffaaf start
```

Comment: Do you set the ivar `player` outside a setter?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad,I didn't understand what you mean by outside a setter.I am doing following
@property(nonatomic,strong)AVPlayer* player;
self.player = player; // player is an avplayer object.

Comment: Please, add code to the Q, not to the comments. I mean: Do you have code like "`_player = newPlayer`" instead of using the dot notation or explicit setters?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad,No I don't have code like  "_player = newPlayer" , I used dot notation for assigning player object.Can you please tell what are you suspecting from this issue.

Comment: Direct assignment does not trigger KVO.

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: any solution for this?